# Data insertion in SQL Server table using jtextfield in netbeans

Tags: sql, sql-server, jtextfield, netbeans-8

I am trying to insert data typed in by user in SQL Server table using below code, the code runs without any error but data is not inserted.

```
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    String sql="insert into inventory"
                +"(Product_Code,Product_Name,Quantity,Cost)"
                +"value(?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, product_code.getText());
    pst.setString(2, product_name.getText());
    pst.setString(3, quantity.getText());
    pst.setString(4, price.getText()); 
    pst.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "entry successful");    
}                                    
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "entry successful"); 
}
```

Comment: `Quantity,Cost` --> `getText()`? try to convert into integer/float

Comment: still not able to insert rows

Comment: What exactly do you pass in that parameters? Can you show sample of data?

Comment: product code: a0001, product name:rice 2 kg , quantity:45, price 454. all are varchar except price which is float

Comment: And `quantity` is not numeric? Are you sure?

Comment: What happen, if you use `con.commit();  pst.close();` after the `pst.executeUpdate();`?

Comment: yes quantity is numeric

Comment: pst.setInt(3, (Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText())));
           pst.setFloat(4,(Float.parseFloat(price.getText())));                               i chnged it to this stll not working

Comment: do u think there is a problem in the database connection????

Comment: @MohitJoshi it might be

Comment: do i need to give the port name while setting the connectioin with the local database

Comment: Try it like `String url= "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433";` Also check the code from my answer, I remove typo with values and add datatype changes and checking if connection is established

Comment: i corrected the typos but the connection name of my datatbase is different so i will write that

Comment: You need to change the `catch` block to show the error message, otherwise, we cannot help you much. Use `e.printStackTrace(System.out);` instead of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "entry successful"); `. If there's an exception, then it's a failure and not a success in any case.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Microsoft SQL Server 2012
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Microsoft SQL Server 2012       it is showing this exception

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'value'.  this is the message i am getting. can u tell me to how correct it @Mincong Huang

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your reply. Incorrect syntax near `value`, because in SQL, it should be `values` instead of `value` as indicated by @gofr1.

Comment: thanks alot . silly mistake

Comment: can u tell me how to add validation so that user cant enter same product code and empty values @gofr1

Comment: You could add some triggers on your table to work with that, but it is another question :) hope your code works well now.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in the below [`INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx) script:

```
 String sql="insert into inventory"
             +"(Product_Code,Product_Name,Quantity,Cost)"
             +"value(?,?,?,?)";
```

Typo in the `value(` it should be `values(`, so your code will be:

```
String sql="insert into inventory"
         +" (Product_Code, Product_Name, Quantity, Cost)"
         +" values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: still not able to insert values in the table

Answer (score 0):

Based on commentaries I suggest you to try this code:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=YourDBName;integratedSecurity=false;user=MyUserName;password=*****;";

try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    if (con!= null) {
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }

    String sql="insert into inventory"
                +" (Product_Code,Product_Name,Quantity,Cost)"
                +" values (?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, product_code.getText());
    pst.setString(2, product_name.getText());
    pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()));
    pst.setFloat(4, Float.parseFloat(price.getText())); 

    int rowsInserted = pst.executeUpdate();
    if (rowsInserted > 0) {
        System.out.println("A new row was inserted successfully!");
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "entry successful");    
}                                    
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "entry successful"); 
}
```

Comment: error "dereferencing possible null pointer" is showing in the line      "PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);"

Comment: So connection was established? Did you get `Connected` message?

Comment: And I changed `url` you need to change DB name user and password.

Comment: now i am getting this msg.                   ( ant -f C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\qseal -Djavac.includes=qseal/AddItem.java -Dnb.internal.action.name=run.single -Drun.class=qseal.AddItem run-single
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qseal\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qseal\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qseal\build\classes
compile-single:
run-single:
Connected
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 38 seconds).)