# populating jtable with sql server database

Tags: sql-server, jtable, populate

```
public InventoryJFrame() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        initComponents();
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" );
        StringstringCon="jdbc:sqlserver://AAYANPC;databaseName=Qseal;user=sa;password=123";

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(stringCon);
        Statement state=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=state.executeQuery("select * from Qseal");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata=rs.getMetaData();
        int columns=rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
        DefaultTableMode1 dtm=new DefaultTableMode1();
    }   
    catch (SQLException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(InventoryJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

i get a error in the line `DefaultTableMode1 dtm=new DefaultTableMode1();`. The error is "cannot find symbol" and in the hint it says that create a pachkage DefaultTableName in source pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

> A "Cannot find symbol" error is about the identifiers. When your code is compiled, the compiler needs to work out what each and every identifier in your code means.
>
> A "Cannot find symbol" error means that the compiler cannot do this. **Your code appears to be referring to something that the compiler doesn't understand.**

I suppose you have a spelling error when taping [`DefaultTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html). It ends with the character `l` instead of the digit `1`.

Comment: how do i type digit 1 instead of character 1

Comment: @MohitJoshi, it's an L, not one.

Comment: @MohitJoshi, copy this line `DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel();`

Comment: It's my pleasure. Can you accept my answer ? By the way, I don't recommand you to use admin account `sa` for you application, it can cause severe security issue. Check [why should an application not use the sa account](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39124/why-should-an-application-not-use-the-sa-account)

Comment: i am new here . how can i give u the link of another question in asked on this forum.

Comment: Do you mean [Data insertion in SQL Server table using jtextfield in netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092655/data-insertion-in-sql-server-table-using-jtextfield-in-netbeans) ? You can use the [markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to give the URL.

Comment: There's a check mark on the left side of my answer, just under the number 0. @MohitJoshi

Comment: Thank, bro @MohitJoshi